# Count how many month had passed

Tags: sql, oracle

It goes like

```
SELECT fname, date_emped
FROM   table_1
```

Then it gave me the table

```
fname | date_emped
------------------
John  | 03-JAN-07
Smith | 02-JAN-08
```

I wanted to count how many months they had employed or worked here up until today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not champ in orcale but this might do

```html
 SELECT fname, date_emped, MONTHS_BETWEEN 
   (SYSDATE,
    date_emped) "Months"
FROM   table_1
```

Comment: I got a long line: 430.517998058542413381123058542413381123 . Was this suppose to happened?

Comment: Try ROUND(MONTHS_BETWEEN 
   (SYSDATE,
    date_emped), 0)

Answer (score 2):

```
select          months_between (sysdate,dateemped) 
               ,floor (months_between (sysdate,dateemped))

from            table_1 
;
```

Comment: @oncik, please check

Answer (score 2):

```
TRY THIS (In SQL)
```

SELECT fname, date_emped , DATEDIFF(MONTH,date_emped,GETDATE()) 
FROM   table_1

Comment: He needs solution in oracle.

Answer (score 0):

select floor(sysdate-date_emped)/365 as Year_worked,
       floor(sysdate-date_emped)/30 as Month_worked,
       floor(sysdate-date_emped) as days_worked from employees

Comment: Please check it